# nginx ./configure error ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nginx

after downloading and trying to configure nginx when um executing the command ./configure
um getting this error

```
./configure: error: the HTTP rewrite module requires the PCRE library.
You can either disable the module by using --without-http_rewrite_module
option, or install the PCRE library into the system, or build the PCRE library
statically from the source with nginx by using --with-pcre=<path> option.
```

and I execute the

```
apt-get build-dep nginx
```

command um getting the following error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgd2-noxpm-dev : Depends: libgd2-noxpm (= 2.0.36~rc1~dfsg-6ubuntu2) but it is not    going to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for nginx could not be satisfied.
```

I dont have any idea about the libgd2-noxpm. This is my first time with nginx . how to overcome from this error . Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe just install the `libpcre3-dev` package and try again?

Comment: thank you seems like working. Documentation does not say anything about the third party dependencies

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You have to install pcre3:

`apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`

The library is required for regular expressions support in the location directive and for the ngx_http_rewrite_module module. http://nginx.org/en/docs/install.html

Comment: This required me to also install libgd2-noxpm-dev

Answer (score 15):

apt-get build-dep nginx

just resolved my problem....

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps that you need to follow for Nginx installation on Ubuntu 18.04:

1: Install build essential
sudo apt-get install build-essential

You may receive "udo  apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev"

2: sudo  apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev

3: sudo  apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev

4: sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev

Answer (score 0):

For someone who met same issue under CentOS system:

```
yum -y install pcre-devel openssl openssl-devel
```